# Can not save to Windows 7 libraries from 32 bit appications using Windows 7 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-7

When I am in a 32 bit application I can not save file to the "libraries" - I have to navigate through the "C" drive to the location on disk I want to save the file - the same is true for the reverse where in a 32 bit app I can't browse to file in a library and attach it or open it - I have to navigate through "C" . For example if I am in 32 bit Lotus Notes and want to save an attachment - I right click select save as and try to go to my Documents Library and click save I get "the specified module could not be found" . I then navigate down through C/users/username/ documents and settings/ documents and can save their just fine. I have checked indexing settings , permissions , various other port to forums , etc... 64 bit apps work fine

Based on the comments below - I installed 32bit Opera and have the same issue - see screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Which applications ?

Comment: any 32 bit application - Lotus Notes - Firefox - IE , etc...

Answer (score 2):

According to what you describe, this is a 64/32-bit problem.

It is possibly caused by the fact the 32-bit programs on 64-bit Windows do not see the same registry keys as do 64-bit programs. This Microsoft article describes the registry keys that are affected:
[Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

One can view the redirected 32-bit registry by using `%systemroot%\syswow64\regedit`, as described here : 
[How to view the system registry by using 64-bit versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097).

Now comes the hard part, which is to find which registry entries are responsible for describing the Libraries. It is evident that they are badly defined for 32-bit programs.
There are two possibilities:

1. They have been redirected and contain wrong values, or
2. They have not been redirected but should have been because the 64-bit values do not work for 32-bit programs.

I have searched the registry on my computer for "Pictures", and have come with the following candidates:

```
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`  
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
```

which I remark are not in the list of redirected registry keys.
So option 2 above is probably indicated as correct.

The following article contains some more pointers to registry keys :
[How To Disable and Remove Libraries from Windows 7 Explorer](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/05/how-to-disable-and-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorer/).

As I do not have Windows 7 64-bit, this is as far as I can go. You would need to find out what these keys contain on your computer, and whether they are redirected or not. With more information, I could possibly advance some more.

Comment: happens in safe mode - the logic of saving to a library is rather than click 7 times through C then users, then user name...etc... I just save to Pictures - I could certainly set up shortcuts as a workaround - but I would rather solve the problem. To clarify , if I use IE 64 bit and right click an image and select save as I can save to a Windows 7 library like Pictures - if I use 32 bit IE and do the exact  same thing I get the error mentioned above - I then navigate through the file system starting at "C" drill down to My Pictures where the Pictures library is pointing and can save no problem

Comment: I verified, and it does work in Win7 32-bits. So this is a 32/64-bit problem. Could you please repeat the Save As in both bitness modes, just in order to click on the bread-crumb bar to display the real directory. Is it "Libraries\Pictures" in both cases?

Comment: @alevenso: I did some more research into the problem. See my edit above.

Comment: to clarify - any library fails - whether its a default out of the box Windows 7 library (pictures, documents , etc) or a brand new library - any 32 bit app (not just Lotus Notes) will fail to save to a library from any UI . All 64 bot apps work fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some software installed on your client which is overriding standard Save functionality?
Can you do a screen print of your save dialog. Also - can you install 32 bit opera and see if this gives the same error.

Comment: I just validated the registry settings and they appear to all point to the correct paths going to investigate disabling libraries and see what effect that has.

Comment: I tried disabling libraries - and they do get disabled in Explorer - but when I do a save image as(Firefox)  or save (Lotus Notes) that UI still has libraries and I still cant save (no surprise) . I then re-enabled libraries hoping for some jolt in the system and divine intervention but still no joy.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the same behavior in 32bit Opera above - I do not believe I have anything installed that would override "saves" as with a 64 bit app it works fine -

Comment: This looks like a Microsoft bug, as I said a registry entry that should have had been redirected. Why don't you report it at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file into a library, it will save the file into one of the library folders. 
This folder the files are saved in is the folder ticked in the library properties screen, and marked as "set save location"

[image]

I have confirmed that this works when running 32bit Applications in 64bit Windows.

Comment: you are right - I have also tested this on many systems and it works - however , my problem is that it does not work on my system in question .

Comment: Looks like it's the same issue as this. http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/65956-cant-save-files-libraries-via-browser-2.html

Comment: yes thats my post in Seven Forums

Answer (score 0):

just to update this - I ended up buying a solid state drive and reinstalling the OS to that drive on this system and low and behold the problem is gone - so whatever I did when I installed the first time I did not do this time and all is well in the world -